Passing Makefile Variables into Kernel Modules
I'd like to grab information from the shell and pass it into a kernel module through the makefile. I can do this with user space programs using -D.
Is there a similar mechanism for kernel modules? For example, if I define a makefile variable
CURRENT_DATE := '"$(shell date +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")"'

I can get a hold of that date as a string in the user space program by appending -DCURRENT_DATE to the end of the build command. Is there a way to do this with kernel modules?

I don't understand the question, You know about shell, Are you asking about building kernel modules? Have you seen https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/kbuild/index.html

The question pertains to kernel module builds with make. Say I want to embed a variable value in the module when it's built to identify the build date. With user space programs built using make, I can pass variables with -D<var_name> and have the C program copy the string encoded as <var_name> when it starts. Is there a similar mechanism for passing variables through the build process with modules?
